# Why am I getting a default IBM webservice message when I try to hit this webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, soapui

I apologize that this may be a little ambiguous, but I am completely stumped and I really don't know very much about webservices or SOAP.

Recently, a webservice began responding with:

```
<h2>{http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/commerce/9/order}OrderServices</h2>
<h3>Hi there, this is a Web service!</h3>
```

This only started happening recently, but I have no idea how it was changed or how to change it.  Where in Websphere would I go to change what happens when this webservice gets invoked?  I know what classes should be getting invoked and what the response usually looks like, but I have no idea where to configure the response of a webservice.

The url I'm hitting via SOAPUI is

http://localhost/webapp/wcs/component/order/services/OrderServices

though I think this might be custom and thus meaningless to provide.

TL;DR:

How do I change the webservice configuration so that I no longer see IBM's default webservice response and instead see a response of my choosing?

Comment: It is difficult to offer any thing based on the information provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Both the JAX-RPC and JAX-WS runtimes in WebSphere will return a message like that when you hit (contextRoot)/(ServiceName) with a browser.  There is no way to customize this message.

The only way that I can get the symptoms that you describe is to use a GET in the HTTP message that I send with SOAPUI instead of a POST.  A SOAP request is sent with a POST, not a GET.